# How do I repeat an event handler a set number of times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my code...

```
handleGenNums()
{
    const genNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 70);

    if (this.state.nums.indexOf(genNum) === -1)
    {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                nums: this.state.nums.concat(genNum)
            }
        });
     } 
     else
     {
        this.handleGenNums();
     }
}

// handlePlayLottery() {
//     while (this.state.nums.length <= 5) {
//         this.handleGenNums();
//     }
// }
```

I have a button that inserts one number into an array. I want to hit the button once, but have 5 numbers in my array. I commented out the code I tried cuz it broke my browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're looking for more thoroughly?

Comment: I want handleGenNums to run 5 times when the button is clicked instead of just once.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll try these out in a bit. Sorry if this was a noob question, but I am, in fact, a noob.

Comment: I think my solution here may be to make each number a separate prop on the state as opposed to adding them into a single array.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to reuse this functionality you can simply use a helper function that calls a function a certain number of times:

```
function callFunction(fn, n) {
  if (n <= 0) return;
  fn();
  callFunction(fn, --n);
}
```

```js
function callFunction(fn, n) {
  if (n <= 0) return;
  fn();
  callFunction(fn, --n);
}
 
callFunction(() => console.log("test"), 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to do this using recursive features. Explanation is within the code.

```
handleGenNums(counter)
{
    // Check if we have to generate another number.

    if (counter <= 0)
        return;

    // Generate a random number.

    const genNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 70);

    // Check if the generated number already is in the array.
    // If number is not found, add the number, and call recursively
    // the method with counter decremented. If element exists, call
    // recursively again without decrementing the counter.

    if (this.state.nums.indexOf(genNum) === -1)
    {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                nums: this.state.nums.concat(genNum)
            }
        });

        this.handleGenNums(counter - 1);
     } 
     else
     {
        this.handleGenNums(counter);
     }
}
```

Now, if you want to generate 5 random numbers, just call:

```
handleGenNums(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call the event handler a certain number of times based on some condition then just use:
`if(array.length < 5) {
  this.handleFunction();
}`